# Implementing Message Security in NETCF

Tags: wcf, compact-framework, x509

As far as I know only a subset of WS-Security version 1.0 is supported in NETCF and it uses X.509 certificates.
How can I obtain such a certificate to implement it in my application and prevent others to use my WCF service?